# why iptables is accepting all in INPUT?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

As we can see in this, which is the default iptables on fedora 20

```
$ iptables -L INPUT --line-number
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
3    INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
4    INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
5    INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
6    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
7    REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

for rule 2, why is it accepting all the targets?

Comment: Is this a fresh install? Have you configured IPTABLES? Have you added any chains? Is this a server? You give very little information to help us answer the question

Comment: The output of `iptables-save` would be much clearer than `iptables -L`, which often omits information.

Comment: add `-v` (v=verbose output) to see the incomming-address.

Answer (score 2):

As we can see:

```
# iptables -S INPUT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

"-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT", that is the problem, iptables -L missed the lo information.